# $\sqrt{x}$ is a constant function?

Tags: real-analysis, logic, fake-proofs

I just "proved" something ridiculous and can't find the fault in my logic. It's probably something really simple and obvious that I'm just overlooking, or maybe not because none of my friends can find the logic gap either.

> **Theorem:** Let $f:U\to\Bbb{R}$ be a non-negative, non-decreasing, differentiable function where $U\subseteq\Bbb{R}$. If there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ such that for all $x,\ y\in U$ such that $x \ge y$, $f$ satisfies
>   $$
> f(x) - f(y) \le (x - y)^{1+\epsilon}
> $$
>   then $f(x)$ is a constant function.

Note: The $\epsilon$ in the theorem is *constant*. In the following "example", take $\epsilon = 1$ and everything should still hold.

Proof:
$$
f'(x_0) = \lim_{x\to x_0^+}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x - x_0}\le\lim_{x\to x_0^+}\frac{(x-x_0)^{1+\epsilon}}{(x-x_0)}=\lim_{x\to x_0^+}(x-x_0)^{\epsilon}=0
$$
but since we assumed $f$ is non-decreasing, it's derivative is never negative. Thus we have $0 \le f'(x) \le 0$ which implies $f'(x) = 0$.

Now let $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$, with $U = \{x\ge 1\}$. Clearly${}^*$, $\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y} \le (x - y)^{1+\epsilon}$, and $\sqrt{x}$ is non-negative, non-decreasing, and differentiable. The theorem above thus states that $f'(x) = 0$.

$*$ - First show $\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y} \le x - y$, which is equivalent to showing that $\sqrt{x} - x \le \sqrt{y} - y$ which is true because $\sqrt{x} - x$ is a decreasing function on the interval $[1/4,\infty)$ and $x \ge y$.

Comment: “Clearly” is not that  clearly.

Comment: @Akatsuki Alright I'll add that in.

Comment: And then? Notice that you cannot have $x-y \leq (x-y)^{(1+\epsilon)}$.

Comment: @Akatsuki I don't understand - if $x-y<1$, then there is indeed a positive $\epsilon$ such that $x-y\le (x-y)^{(1+\epsilon)}$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Think twice.

Comment: @Akatsuki That's very good advice; d'oh!

Comment: @Akatsuki: You should post your comment as an answer: it's much better than what is currently on offer. It is noteworthy that the use of $\sqrt{}$ here is a red herring as the "proof" applies just as well to the identity function.

Comment: The "proof" also requires $U$ to be connected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y} \le (x - y)^{1+\epsilon} \Leftrightarrow \frac{x-y}{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}} \le (x - y)^{1+\epsilon}\Leftrightarrow 1 \le (x - y)^{\epsilon} (\sqrt{x} +\sqrt{y})$$

But $ 1 \le (x - y)^{\epsilon} (\sqrt{x} +\sqrt{y})$ cannot be true as the RHS goes to $0$ when $y \to x$.

Comment: But the LHS also goes to zero as $y\rightarrow x$ . . .

Comment: @NoahSchweber The LHS of the last inequality is 1.

Comment: Whoops, quite right. Although this also suffers from implicit quantifier reversal: the OP claims that for every $1\le x<y$, there is some $\epsilon>0$ such that the inequality holds; when you take the limit, you're leaving $\epsilon$ fixed, but that's not correct.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I disagree, as in his "counterexample" the $\epsilon$ is supposed to be independent on $x$. But his "proof" is based on the fact that for any $\epsilon$ we have $(x-y) \leq (x-y)^{1+\epsilon}$ which is wrong... Change the quantifiers in the proper order and his question still stands.

Comment: @NoahSchweber You should not delete your answer though, as it pointed one of the mistakes in the original post ;)

Comment: "N. S." and "Noah Schweber"? Are you sure you're not the same person?

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger Oh dear, I hadn't noticed that at all. :P

Comment: @N.S. I think at this point my answer adds more heat than light - let's keep it down to one clear mistake that can't be fixed by rearranging quantifiers. (Also, I was the initial downvoter due to hasty reading; I've since un-downvoted and upvoted.)

Comment: Alright I think this is it. So there's nothing wrong with the theorem, only the example?